# Automatically select drop-down after visiting on specific page

Tags: html, javascript

I have drop-down list, where user can select any options when they register on my site.
I like to make it more easier for example if user vist specific url. They will automatically selected on Publishers opinion when they visit on domain.com/register#publishers

here is my code:

```
<div class="select_box">
 <select name="registared_as" id="registared_as">
 <option value="0">Students / Experts</option>
 <option value="1">University Academics</option>
 <option value="2">Publishers</option>
 </select>
 </div>
```

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re asking. You posted HTML code, but you can’t do what you’re asking in HTML. You’re going to need JavaScript or some server side processing to dynamically generate or change the HTML. You can set an item as selected by simply adding `selected` after the value name. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element/amp/

Answer (score 1):

If the trigger is an url anchor, like your example with domain.com/register#publishers you can get the url anchor using javascript vanilla like this:

```
var anchor = window.location.hash.substr(1);
```

Then, you must select the option, also with javascript:

```
if (anchor == "publishers") {
     document.getElementById("registared_as").selectedIndex = 2;
}
```

And so on for each option..